# ラズベリーパイにてsystemdを用い、pythonプログラムを自動起動させたいです。

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, systemd

プログラミングに関しては初心者です。
現在、ラズベリーパイの起動と同時にpythonプログラムを実行したいと考えております。

インターネット等を検索調査し、systemdを使うと起動と同時にpythonプログラムも起動できる事が解り、作成しましたが、何度やってもエラーが出てきます。

systemed,pythonを見直しても原因が分からないので、ご教示お願いいたします。

ラズベリーパイの電源on/offはRPZ-PowerMGRを購入し対応しました。

systemdコード
/etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description = test
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/RasPiSample/bin/2.2.1_Photoresistor.py
Restart=always
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Pythonのコード

```
#!usr/bin/python3.7.3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import ADC0834
import datetime
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。

systemd と Python に関しては下記で問題なく稼働しました。

何をやりたかったかというと、光センサーを用いて機械についている信号灯を読み取り稼働率の調査を行っております。

---

**/etc/systemd/system/RasPiAuto.service**

```
[Unit]
Description = test

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/env python3  /opt/RasPiSample/bin/2.2.1_Photoresistor.py

Restart = no
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**Python スクリプト**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import ADC0834
import datetime
import csv
import time

LedPin = 22

def setup():
    global led_val
    # Set the GPIO modes to BCM Numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    # Set all LedPin's mode to output and initial level to High(3.3v)
    GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
    ADC0834.setup()
    # Set led as pwm channel and frequece to 2KHz
    led_val = GPIO.PWM(LedPin, 2000)

    # Set all begin with value 0
    led_val.start(0)

def nowtime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    nowtime = '{0:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(now)


def save():
    with open('/home/pi/Desktop/cp_log.csv','a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now(), ADC0834.getResult()])

def destroy():
    # Stop all pwm channel
    led_val.stop()
    # Release resource
    GPIO.cleanup()

def loop():
    while True:
        analogVal =  ADC0834.getResult()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        nowTime = '{0:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(now)
        save()
        print (nowTime, end='  ')
        print ('CP1 = %d' % analogVal)
        led_val.ChangeDutyCycle(analogVal*100/255)
        time.sleep(0.975)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the program destroy() will be executed.
        destroy()
```

Comment: 質問時と回答時とでアカウントが二つに分かれているようです。ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを行ってください。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

質問に貼られた Python コードでは、1行目 (`#!` 行) に誤りがあるように見えます。
先頭の `/` が足りないようなので、こちらを追加して試してみてください。

**元のコード:**

```
#!usr/bin/python3.7.3
```

**修正後:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7.3
```

Comment: Pythonの位置固定, バージョンも固定なので, (動いたとしても)そのうち動かなくなりそうな。(動作確認後は？) `#!/usr/bin/env python3` がよさそう